# Video playing using Video View in android

Tags: android, android-videoview, seekbar

I have implemented a video player using video view. Default seek bar and buttons for control showing at bottom of screen. I want that it should be in video view itself. How can I achieve this. I am adding code also.

Code for Activity is:

```
 @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
     System.out.println(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/"+R.raw.scotch_cppk));
     mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/"+R.raw.scotch_cppk));
     mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
     mVideoView.start();

   }
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"> 
<VideoView android:id="@+id/surface_view" 
      android:layout_gravity="center" 
      android:layout_width="600dp" 
      android:layout_height="800dp"/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
     
   <VideoView
       android:id="@+id/surface_view"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:layout_width="600dp"
       android:layout_height="800dp"/>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: actually what is your need ?? Where do you want to show the MediaController (seekbar)??