# How to play selected videos from sdcard using VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

I recently created a file chooser. I got it from http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/190013-creating-simple-file-chooser/ and it only shows a text saying "File Chosen - 'filename'".
I wanted it to be played in VideoView.
I tried to google but I couldn't find it.
Can you guys help me out? Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you have the file URl?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is already exist at there :
[How to play videos from SD Card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869830/how-to-play-videos-from-sd-card)

You should pass the URI of the video that's in the SD-Card to the VideoView control.

Couple of helpful links :
http://mrbool.com/how-to-play-video-formats-in-android-using-videoview/28299
[How to play a video from url using videoview smoothly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366378/how-to-play-a-video-from-url-using-videoview-smoothly)
[How to play .mp4 video in videoview in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399351/how-to-play-mp4-video-in-videoview-in-android)
[Video playing using Video View in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15847922/video-playing-using-video-view-in-android)